# What are the differences between editions of Ryle's Expository Thoughts?

Tags: books, jc-ryle

I've heard J.C. Ryle's devotional thoughts on the gospels ("Expository Thoughts") highly recommended by a few people.

However there are a few editions out there, and different people have different opinions on which is best. However, I haven't found anywhere that clearly lists the differences between the text of the editions.

Can anyone help?

Editions I'm aware of (there are likely many more!):

- [Banner of Truth's 7 volume 2012 version](https://banneroftruth.org/uk/store/sermons-and-expositions/expository-thoughts-on-the-gospels-16/)
- [Baker's 4-volume version](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Expository-Thoughts-Gospels-Four-Vol/dp/0801077559?tag=skim0x15452-21)